# how to insert into vector under condition without use loop?

Tags: c++

I would like to copy elements from one vector which meet certain criteria in to another vector, but without using a hand-written loop.  For example,

```
std::vector<double> source; // somehow filled elsewhere
std::vector<double> result;

for( std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); ++it )
{
   if ((*it) % 2)
   {
      result.push_back(*it);
   }
}
```

The above code uses a hand-written loop to populate `result`.  How can this be done without a hand-written loop?

Comment: your code only has _one_ vector. Why?

Comment: I think I get what is being asked here, have made extensive edits & nominated to re-open.  It may then be closed again as a dupe, but that's a different thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::copy_if()` and `std::back_inserter()` to do so. To get the initial sequence with suitable values you can use `std::generate_n()`. I could type things out but you'd be better off doing the homework.

Comment: Yes, recursion would work. I think `std::generate_n()` together with a lambda is simpler than recursion. The generator would be something like `int i(-2); <:=:>() mutable <% return i += 2; %>`

Comment: @DietmarKühl What is that syntax? I've never seen it before! (Seems to compile only in C++0x) I thought the standard lambda syntax was `[] {...}`...

Comment: @David: it's the same syntax, except with digraphs.  (Who uses digraphs?)

Comment: @David: Given that we are clearly talking about a homework assignment I thought I say what I mean in a way comprehensible to people who know what I'm talking of without revealing the solution to the homework :) Look at digraphs.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Clever, digraphs as obfuscation.

Comment: is it possible to combine std::copy_if() and boost::bind. In fact I need to call element of vector member function to get value to build new vector.